# Replace a blank space followed by text with a blank space using string replace

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a log file from which i am trying to remove all the unwanted text except the digits(0-9). I am able to use string.replace('','') function to remove everything and get the desired, however, at a couple of places, i still have a blank space followed by some text towards the end of the element in the string.

eg. i was able to get `12345` from

```
ansd: 12345,43556
```

however, i still have a few elements that are in the form

```
 12345 hdjhdjf dfdfd "dfd".
```

Can anyone help me understand how to use replace for this particular problem?

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the formatting... please check to make sure I haven't accidentally changed what you were trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*').findall('12345 hdjhdjf dfdfd "dfd".')
['12345']
>>> re.compile('[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*').findall('ansd: 12345,43556')
['12345']
```

EDIT - how about this?

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('([^\d]*([0-9]+)[^\d]*)+').findall('12345 hdjhdjf dfdfd "dfd" 12333.')
[('12333', '12333')]
>>>
```

OR to sub all non-digits with blank spaces

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[^\d]', ' ', '12345 hdjhdjf dfdfd "dfd" 12333.')
'12345                     12333 '
```

OR to sub all digits with blank spaces

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[0-9]', ' ', '12345 hdjhdjf dfdfd "dfd" 12333.')
'      hdjhdjf dfdfd "dfd"      .'
>>>
```

Comment: It is not the same string all the time, they are different elements in the string. I need a more generic form that i can use to get rid of the below mentioned format.

(digits)(whitespaces)(text a-z)(.,:"")

Comment: look again. The part with the string is supposed to be a variable, the regex is the part with the \d

Comment: I am sorry, I think, the way i phrased my question was not appropriate. I have a string that consists of a huge list of IDs. There are a few IDs that are not in the format that i need them to be in.
Like, 12345 dfsdfsdf dsgfsg"asfda".
34543223 diosoidfh jdshfoshdo_sdjfk.
76857 jkfhdjhdfj

I need to get the digits separate from the entire element in the string and replace it with a blank space.

Comment: It helps, however I was hoping to get something where i could use a replace function to replace the unwanted part with a blank space. Can you help with that ?

Comment: Its there. If you want to replace characters with blank spaces, look at code block #3. Instead of the string as the 3rd argument, use your "huge list of IDs".

Comment: am not sure but i think this worked: string.replace('[a-zA-Z]*',' ')
Just to share.

Comment: Everything tells me that will not work. If "string" if your variable, name then re.sub('[^\d]', ' ', string) should work.